# How press button produces random options every time?

Tags: jquery, button, random

```js
 $(function () {
            $("#question2").hide();
            const options = [$("#option1"), $("#option2"), $("#option3"), $("#option4")];

           let randomOption =function (){const texts = options
                .map(opt => opt[0].textContent)
                .sort(() => .5 - Math.random());

            $("#option1").text(texts[0]);
            $("#option2").text(texts[1]);
            $("#option3").text(texts[2]);
            $("#option4").text(texts[3]);}



            $("#question1 button").click(function () {
                $("#question1").fadeOut();
                $("#question2").fadeIn();randomOption()
            })
            $("#question2 button").click(function () {
                $("#question2").fadeOut();
                $("#question1").fadeIn();randomOption()
            })

            console.log(randomOption())
           

        })
```

```html
 <div id="question1">question 1
        <button id=option1>1</button>
        <button id=option2>2</button>
        <button id=option3>3</button>
        <button id=option4>4</button>
    </div>
    <div id="question2">question 2
        <button id=option1>1</button>
        <button id=option2>2</button>
        <button id=option3>3</button>
        <button id=option4>4</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

Why function call does not work.

When I press question2 button.

question2 options not random? even call randomOption().

What is wrong with this code?

console.log(randomOption()) is undefined ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button's element is get selected on jquery by `id` and `id` should be **unique** to be call only **once**, In this case `$("#option1")` to `$("#option4")` only effected once in `<div id="question1">` so solution is change from `id` to `class`.

```js
 $(function () {
            $("#question2").hide();
            const options = [$(".option1"), $(".option2"), $(".option3"), $(".option4")];

           let randomOption =function (){const texts = options
                .map(opt => opt[0].textContent)
                .sort(() => .5 - Math.random());

            $(".option1").text(texts[0]);
            $(".option2").text(texts[1]);
            $(".option3").text(texts[2]);
            $(".option4").text(texts[3]);}



            $("#question1 button").click(function () {
                $("#question1").fadeOut();
                $("#question2").fadeIn();randomOption()
            })
            $("#question2 button").click(function () {
                $("#question2").fadeOut();
                $("#question1").fadeIn();randomOption()
            })

            console.log(randomOption())
           

        })
```

```html
  <div id="question1">question 1
        <button class=option1>1</button>
        <button class=option2>2</button>
        <button class=option3>3</button>
        <button class=option4>4</button>
    </div>
    <div id="question2">question 2
        <button class=option1>1</button>
        <button class=option2>2</button>
        <button class=option3>3</button>
        <button class=option4>4</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```